# How to alias a column in Spark SQL struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
sparkSession.sql("select struct(col1,col2) as myStruct from table1")
```

return the dataframe with following schema

```
root
 |-- myStruct : struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

But I need  **col1** as **myCol1** and **col2** as **myCol2**?

When I use **as** keyword inside struct function, it fails

```
sparkSession.sql("select struct(col1 as myCol1,col2 as myCol2) as myStruct from table1")
```

gives the below error message

```
mismatched input 'as' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 19)
```

How to get column alias in **struct** field?

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use? I just tried on 2.3 and works for me fine: scala> sql("select struct(user as l, movie as p) as mystruct from table").printSchema root |-- mystruct: struct (nullable = false) | |-- l: integer (nullable = true) | |-- p: integer (nullable = true)

Comment: Spark 2.1.0 version

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in Spark 2.1.0 on the created DF

```
val newDF = oldDF.withColumn("MyCol",struct($"myCol.col1".alias("myCol1"),$"myCol.col2".alias("myCol2"))).drop("myCol").withColumnRenamed("MyCol","myCol")
```

Comment: this is also not working .. extraneous input '$' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', .....

Comment: you have to `import spark.implicits._` before you can refer column with '$'